# How can I access an ontology from RDFLib?

Tags: triplestore, rdflib, blazegraph

How can I connect to a triple store and access an ontology through the RDFLib Python API?

The triple store I am using is Blazegraph. I know how to access Virtuso, but about Blazegraph I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the Blazegraph [SPARQL Endpoint](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/REST_API#SPARQL_End_Point) to configure it.

For the default namespace, using the executable jar this is:

```
http://localhost:9999/bigdata/sparql
```

With a specific namespace (kb in this example), it is:

```
https://localhost:9999/bigdata/namespace/kb/sparql
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to access the triple store via SPARQL with [SPARQLWrapper](http://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/).